# DOMElement replace HTML value

Tags: php, dom, preg-replace, domdocument, dom-node

I have this HTML string in a `DOMElement`:

```
<h1>Home</h1>
test{{test}}
```

I want to replace this content in a way that only

```
<h1>Home</h1>
test
```

remains (so I want to remove the `{{test}}`).

At this moment, my code looks like this:

```
$node->nodeValue = preg_replace(
    '/(?<replaceable>{{([a-z0-9_]+)}})/mi', '' , $node->nodeValue);
```

This doesn't work because `nodeValue` doesn't contain the HTML value of the node.
I can't figure out how to get the HTML string of the node other than using `$node->C14N()`, but by using `C14N` I can't replace the content.
Any ideas how I can remove the `{{test}}` in an HTML string like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `DOMDocument::saveXML` function? (http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php)

It has a second argument `$node` with which you can specify which node to print the HTML/XML of.

So, for example:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
// we want a nice output
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('body');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$title = $doc->createElement('h1', 'Home');
$root->appendChild($title);

$text = $doc->createTextNode('test{{test}}');
$text = $root->appendChild($text);

echo $doc->saveXML($root);

?>
```

This will give you:

```
<body>
  <h1>Home</h1>
  test{{test}}
</body>
```

If you do not want the `<body>` tag, you could cycle through all of its childnodes:

```
<?php

foreach($root->childNodes as $child){    
    echo $doc->saveXML($child);
}

?>
```

This will give you:

```
<h1>Home</h1>test{{test}}
```

Edit: you can then of course replace `{{test}}` by the regex that you are already using:

```
<?php

$xml = '';
foreach($root->childNodes as $child){    
    $xml .= preg_replace(
                '/(?<replaceable>{{([a-z0-9_]+)}})/mi', '', 
                $doc->saveXML($child)
    );
}

?>
```

This will give you:

```
<h1>Home</h1>test
```

Note: I haven't tested the code, but this should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is mainly around how you navigate the DOM but there's also an issue with your RegExp; XPath actually provides a lot of flexibility when it comes to DOM manipulation so that's my preferred solution.

Assuming you have a DOMDocument built like this (I've attached an XPath):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$node = $dom->createElement('div');
$node->appendChild(
    $dom->createElement('h1', "Home")
    );
$node->appendChild(
    $dom->createTextNode("test{{test}}")
    );

$dom->appendChild($node);
```

You can specifically target the text node of that `<div>` with `'/div/text()'` in XPath.

So to replace `{{test}}` within that text node without corrupting the rest of the node, you would do:

```
$xpath->query('/div/text()')->item(0)->nodeValue = preg_replace(
        '/(.*){{[^}]+}}/m', 
        '$1',
        $xpath->query('/div/text()')->item(0)->nodeValue
);
```

Somewhat convoluted but the output from `$dom->saveXML();` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<div><h1>Home</h1>test</div>
```

`{{test}}` has been removed leaving the rest intact.

Comment: I only have the DOMElement node available at the moment, I can't use the dom or xpath. Or I should load the child as xpath as well.

Comment: You could just load the node into a DOMDocument with a "made up" `root` node - then just extract the original element when you've done manipulating it.