# Using PHP DOM replaceChild to replace a node with a text node

Tags: php, dom

I'm walking a DOMDocument and when I get to certain tags I need to retain their content but remove the tag. To do this I am trying to replace the original node with a text node.

```
$child = $section->childNodes->item($i);
switch ($child->tagName) {
  case 'dontNeedIt':
    $child->parentNode->replaceChild(new DOMText($child->textContent), $child);
```

After which I expect $child to be a text node, but there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I have simply taken a string value where put some tags of anchors and replacing each anchor tag from its Node value.

```
<?php

$contents = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, metus <a href="first.html">First Anchor</a> curabitur orci feugiat aliquam, lorem aenean nobis quisque, pellentesque odio ut, augue duis nisl aliquam tortor inceptos, sed habitasse mauris. Enim eu suspendisse elementum, diam congue aliqua in accumsan eu nunc, cras quam nam magnis. Pellentesque aliquet tristique neque eu faucibus <a href="second.html">Second Anchor</a>, duis nulla. Cursus aliquet faucibus ut, felis sociosqu rhoncus magnis faucibus, urna at nunc euismod mauris. Tortor condimentum natoque metus neque sint in, eu convallis egestas id nulla quisque cupidatat, duis aptent sed nec iaculis praesent elementum. Volutpat velit libero id ridiculus, ut posuere nec. Parturient donec suspendisse, <a>Lorry Ipsum</a> nisl aliquam, venenatis elementum sed suscipit fermentum in, est blandit sagittis luctus ipsum at. Nisl consectetuer molestie ullamcorper senectus velit turpis, <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964378/domelement-replace-html-value">Stack overflow</a> suspendisse erat neque wisi, arcu libero, fringilla vitae pede, turpis molestiae pellentesque. <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php">Contact Us</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($contents);

echo $contents;

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
for ($i = $elements->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i --) {
    $nodePre = $elements->item($i);
    //$nodeDiv = $dom->createElement("span", $nodePre->nodeValue);
    //$nodePre->parentNode->replaceChild($nodeDiv, $nodePre); way to replace with new node
    $nodePre->parentNode->replaceChild(new DOMText($nodePre->nodeValue), $nodePre); // way to replace with node value
}
echo $dom->saveXML(); // $dom->saveHTML() according to requirement

?>
```

**Output:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, metus First Anchor curabitur orci feugiat aliquam, lorem aenean nobis quisque, pellentesque odio ut, augue duis nisl aliquam tortor inceptos, sed habitasse mauris. Enim eu suspendisse elementum, diam congue aliqua in accumsan eu nunc, cras quam nam magnis. Pellentesque aliquet tristique neque eu faucibus Second Anchor, duis nulla. Cursus aliquet faucibus ut, felis sociosqu rhoncus magnis faucibus, urna at nunc euismod mauris. Tortor condimentum natoque metus neque sint in, eu convallis egestas id nulla quisque cupidatat, duis aptent sed nec iaculis praesent elementum. Volutpat velit libero id ridiculus, ut posuere nec. Parturient donec suspendisse, Lorry Ipsum nisl aliquam, venenatis elementum sed suscipit fermentum in, est blandit sagittis luctus ipsum at. Nisl consectetuer molestie ullamcorper senectus velit turpis, Stack overflow suspendisse erat neque wisi, arcu libero, fringilla vitae pede, turpis molestiae pellentesque. Contact Us</p></body></html>
```